# Can't access NSDictionary values

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have an NSDictionary called equiposDic, which I need to retrieve using a value from another NSDictionary (value dip from ) but I can't' access it:

```
   equiposDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"FC Barcelona Regal", @"49", @"Real Madrid", @"50", @"Caja Laboral", @"51", @"Banca Cívica", @"52", @"Gescrap Bizkaia",@"53", @"Valencia Basket", @"13",@"Lucentum Alicante",@"54",@"Lagun Aro GBC",@"4",@"CAI Zaragoza", @"55", @"Assignia Manresa",@"2", @"FIATC Mutua Joventut",@"8",@"Unicaja",@"56",@"Gran Canaria",@"57",@"Mad-Croc Fuenlabrada",@"9",@"Blusens Monbus",@"59",@"UCAM Murcia",@"58", @"Asefa Estudiantes",@"60", @"Blancos de Rueda Valladolid", @"11", nil];


    NSDictionary *posicion = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: [ligaArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSString *equipo = [posicion valueForKey:@"idp"];

    NSString *idp = [posicion valueForKey:@"idp"];

    NSLog(@"equipo %@", [equiposDic objectForKey:@"49"]);
```

Many thanks

Comment: Any runtime errors (EXC_BAD_ACCESS, etc.)?

Comment: No, but the weirdest thing is that NSLog(@"equipo %@", [equiposDic objectForKey:@"49"]); returns the correct value 2012-05-16 18:11:10.690 Lagun Aro Basket[6950:15b03] equipo FC Barcelona Regal. thanks

Comment: Dump the dictionary (with `NSLog(@"equiposDic = %@", equiposDic];`) just before the "49" reference, and make sure it's as you expected.  (I'm guessing the above omits a fair amount of your code.)

Comment: Seems to be ok, look: 2012-05-16 18:24:22.801 Lagun Aro Basket[7085:15b03] equiposDic {
    11 = "Blancos de Rueda Valladolid";
    13 = "Valencia Basket";
    2 = "Assignia Manresa";
    4 = "Lagun Aro GBC";
    49 = "FC Barcelona Regal";
    50 = "Real Madrid";
    51 = "Caja Laboral";
    52 = "Banca C\U00edvica";
    53 = "Gescrap Bizkaia";
    54 = "Lucentum Alicante";
    55 = "CAI Zaragoza";
    56 = Unicaja;
    57 = "Gran Canaria";
    58 = "UCAM Murcia";
    59 = "Blusens Monbus";
    60 = "Asefa Estudiantes";
    8 = "FIATC Mutua Joventut";
    9 = "Mad-Croc Fuenlabrada";
}
Thanks

Comment: Correct, too. It seems to be something weird with this value (dip). I'm trying to use it for loading team shields named with this value from Documents, and despite the path is correct, images are not loaded.

Comment: Is it "dip" or "idp"? Because you used "idp" as the key.

Comment: Note that `valueForKey` has some special-case processing done for NSDictionary.  In particular, if the first char is "@" it behaves differently.  It may be that there is some undocumented behavior for numeric strings.

Answer (score 0):

If posicion is a NSDictionary, you have to use objectForKey in order to get the string.

```
NSString *idp = [posicion objectForKey:@"idp"];
```

Comment: This is not true. `valueForKey:` takes a `NSString` argument for the key, where `objectForKey:` can take any `NSObject` for the key. That is the only difference and doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: I had problems using valueForKey instead of objectForKey, so i think he can try.

Comment: There are certain differences, but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Is ligaArray available in the context ?

I explain, your ligaArray var maynot be available when you expect it. You have to store ligaArray in your class with a retain

.h :

```
@interface MyClass {
    NSMutableArray *ligaArray;
}
```

.m :

```
-viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ligaArray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
    // OR
    ligaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-dealloc{
    [ligaArray release];
}
```

If this is not the case, try it. If it's already the case, check the retain/release calls.
This way, you will not loose reference to ligaArray values in your tableview methods.